# Why can't i edit css files and also use css in django templates?

Tags: django, static-files, appfog

So i decided to deploy my first django app with appfog, created app in appfog, downloaded the source code so as to use their project structure, made the necessary changes and updated. It all went smoothly untill i did `python manage.py collectstatic` this collected all the staticfiles, but i cannot make changes to the static files,cannot use css in the templates. i just don't get why.
in my settings.py

```
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_DIR = /absolute/path/to/static
```

in urls.py

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

my project structure looks like this,basically structure from appfog

```
-env
-.afignore
-settings.py
-templates
-static
-app1
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: hey @catherine, am not getting what you mean..am confused by that statement..``

Comment: now i understand...but it is smart to mess around with django files, coz staticfiles is a django directory right..

Comment: ok,cool let try en get it done

Comment: but you can post your answer for future readers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `run python manage.py collectstatic` it will `create static folder` which `copy the files inside staticfiles folder`, right?

If you want to make changes don't try to change it in your static folder. Just change the files inside your staticfiles folder. After that, run python manage.py collectstatic to make an updates in your static folder.