# Why can't I make changes in my django static files?

Tags: javascript, static-files, django-static

***A bit of context:***

I am taking the CS50W course, and now I'm finishing the almost-completed django Mail single-app provided by the distribution code. Within that distribution code, aside from all python files necessary for the server-side, I have some templates and some static files - these last are causing me problems. For the purpose of this lab, I have no need to touch on a single line of python, everything was already made. I only need to implement new functionalities to a javascript file called inbox.js.

***Real problem:***

The problem is that **any change** that **I make on that javascript file is not saved**, even if am sure that I did it. I mean, **my server simply returns the primer version of the .js file**, like **if any change hasn't been made on it**.

This is my inbox.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// Use buttons to toggle between views
document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

// By default, load the inbox
load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

// Show compose view and hide other views
document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

// Clear out composition fields
document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}
  
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {

// Show the mailbox and hide other views
document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

// Show the mailbox name
document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

I've tried stopping and re-running my server but nothing changed. **Even** when a create **new files** on my static folder and save them, they **are not returned by the server**.

I also tried these two approaches:
1 - [Why can't i edit css files and also use css in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676253/why-cant-i-edit-css-files-and-also-use-css-in-django-templates)
2- [How to change Django static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163187/how-to-change-django-static-files)

Nonetheless, they were inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found **the answer on this post:** [Django won't refresh staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911070/django-wont-refresh-staticfiles)

All that was needed was to refresh the page but cleaning its cache before it.

Comment: This could be a comment instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
control + F5.
You need to clear cache first and that will fix your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).